# Wordpress MU themes and Plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, blogs

I have some X number of blogs setup in the [Wordpress MU](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPressMU) . I need to install themes for each of the blogs.

How do I install themes for them? If I install in the main directory will it work for all the blogs or I need to install for each of the blogs separately as we do in the traditional Wordpress.

Please let me know for plugins as well.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: I think Blog programming is a million dollar industry. So please allow somebody to give their 2 cents. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place them in the `wp-content/themes` directory. You then need to enable them in the admin control panel, via Site Admin > Themes. This allows any blog in the system to use them.

Plugins placed in `wp-content/mu-plugins` are automatically enabled for all blogs in the system. They cannot be turned off by the users.

Plugins placed in `wp-content/plugins` can be enabled on a per-blog basis **if** you allow the user to do so in Site Admin > Options > Menus.